# Is there a browser extension to show upvote and downvote counts in reddit?

Tags: reddit

Reddit's redesign shows net votes (upvotes minus downvotes) and percentage upvoted (upvotes / total votes) on post pages, from which it's quite simple to work out how upvote and downvote counts. Is there a browser extension that does that? Searched all over, to no avail.